# Truncate only urls like twitter

Tags: php, html, regex, twitter

Hi all i need to truncate only urls if it is lengthier from a content like how twitter is doing. If i post,

"hi http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html this".

this content to twitter it will come like this,

"hi …[fatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoing](http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html)… this"

So for me what's the problem is in my content links will in anchor tag. When i tried to use regex to check the links and replace the 'href' value also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using regular expressions, you're doing yourself a disservice.  You shouldn't have to know what it contains, just that it contains a link longer than a certain length.  If that is the case and the content is the link itself, shorten the content of the a tag.

Comment: @Neil content may have some texts also, and more than one link also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution myself here is the code,

```
$stringtest = 'sdsds <a href="http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html">http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> ddfdf';
$regexp= "/\<a.*href=\"(.*?)\".*?\>(.*)\<\/a\>+/";
$text = preg_replace_callback($regexp,
        function($matches) {
        if(strlen($matches[2])>57){
            $returnV="<a target='_blank' href='".$matches[1]."'>".substr($matches[2],0,57).'...'."</a>";
        } else {
         $returnV="<a target='_blank' href='".$matches[1]."'>".substr($matches[2],0,57)."</a>";
        }
            return $returnV;
        },
        $stringtest
        );
print $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help  you. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/zwtfW/) here

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html">http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html</a>
<br>
    <a href="http://www.Hello.com/page/error/view/user/1253" >http://www.Hello.com/page/error/view/user/1253</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").each(function(){
    //var href=$(this).attr("href");
    var text=$(this).text();
    var parts=text.split("/");
    $(this).text(parts[2] +"/"+ parts[3].substr(0,20));
});

});
```

Comment: In javascript this is fine. But i need it in php. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: Now you change the tags dude. Before this is in the Javascript. Ok ill give the php also

Answer (score 1):

For php

```
<?php
$string="<a href='http://www.thelongestliast.com/wearejustdoingthistobdoitanyways.html'>
http://www.thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/wearejustdoingthistobestupidnowsincethiscangoonforeverandeverandeverbutitstilllookskindaneatinthebrowsereventhoughitsabigwasteoftimeandenergyandhasnorealpointbutwehadtodoitanyways.html</a>
<br>
<a href='http://www.Hello.com/page/error/view/user/1253' >http://www.Hello.com/page/error/view/user/1253</a>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $original_url = $node->getAttribute('href');
    $text = explode("/", $original_url);

    echo $var= "<a href='".$original_url."'>".$text[2]."/".$text[3]."</a><br>";


}

?>
```

Comment: thanks. Anyway i got some solution myself without using domdocument.